# Choosing longest ORF with the same stop_codon

Tags: python, dictionary, fasta

I have a set of orthologue sequence files with many proteins containing the same stop codon and I need to choose the longest between them.

I'm not very experienced with programming but I wrote the following script to choose the longest between those of the same species strain - stop codon creating a nested dictionary with the following hierarchy:
all_orfs = {species_strain_1: {stop_codon1: {length1 : identifier1 , length2 : identifier2}}}
And then another dictionary `unique_orfs = {}`with the attempt to only choose the longest orf with the same stop codon within those of the same species through the list `biggest_orf = []` but failed:
`

```
def o_smorf_gatherer(folder, outdir):
    files = os.listdir(folder)

    for file in files:
        all_orfs = {}
        records = SeqIO.parse(f'{folder}/{file}', 'fasta')
        for record in records:
            print(file)
            identifier_parts = identifier.split('_')
            # print(identifier_parts)
            species_strain = '_'.join(identifier_parts[-4:])
            # print(species_strain)
            coordinates = identifier_parts[5]
            codon = coordinates.split('-')
            # print(codon)
            stop_codon = codon[-1]
            # print(stop_codon)
            length = identifier_parts[3]
            # print(length)
            if species_strain not in all_orfs:
                all_orfs[species_strain] = {}
            if stop_codon not in all_orfs[species_strain]:
                all_orfs[species_strain][stop_codon] = {}
            if length not in all_orfs[species_strain][stop_codon]:
                all_orfs[species_strain][stop_codon][length] = {}
            if identifier not in all_orfs[species_strain][stop_codon][length]:
                all_orfs[species_strain][stop_codon][length] = [identifier]
            print(all_orfs)

            for stop_codon in all_orfs[species_strain]:
                longest_orf = None
                longest_seq = 0
                sequence_length = all_orfs[species_strain][stop_codon]
            #     if sequence_length > longest_seq:
            #         longest_seq = sequence_length
            #         longest_orf = all_orfs[species_strain][stop_codon][length]
            #         # print(longest_orf)


            # Now I need to access the length in the dictio
            # print(all_orfs[species_strain][stop_codon])
            biggest_orf = max(all_orfs[species_strain][stop_codon])
            print(biggest_orf)
            unique_orfs = {}
            if biggest_orf not in unique_orfs:
                unique_orfs[biggest_orf] = []
                print(unique_orfs)
```

Here's an example of the fasta input files (they're without the sequences because I don't need them for now:

```
> ORF_150486_LEN_77_COORD_3965185-3965415_forward_NZ_AP022573.1_Mycobacterium_saskatchewanense
> ORF_150484_LEN_81_COORD_3965173-3965415_forward_NZ_AP022573.1_Mycobacterium_saskatchewanense
> ORF_150483_LEN_84_COORD_3965164-3965415_forward_NZ_AP022573.1_Mycobacterium_saskatchewanense
> ORF_150482_LEN_89_COORD_3965149-3965415_forward_NZ_AP022573.1_Mycobacterium_saskatchewanense
> ORF_260114_LEN_92_COORD_5871599-5871874_forward_NZ_CP070348.1_Mycolicibacterium_boenickei
> ORF_260116_LEN_60_COORD_5871695-5871874_forward_NZ_CP070348.1_Mycolicibacterium_boenickei
> ORF_120806_LEN_59_COORD_2912055-2911879_reverse_NZ_AP022612.1_Mycolicibacterium_confluentis
> ORF_120805_LEN_61_COORD_2912061-2911879_reverse_NZ_AP022612.1_Mycolicibacterium_confluentis
> ORF_120803_LEN_69_COORD_2912085-2911879_reverse_NZ_AP022612.1_Mycolicibacterium_confluentis
> ORF_118543_LEN_98_COORD_3460732-3460439_reverse_NZ_AP022560.1_Mycolicibacterium_moriokaense
> ORF_112065_LEN_55_COORD_2618565-2618729_forward_NZ_AP022607.1_Mycobacterium_branderi
> ORF_112067_LEN_53_COORD_2618571-2618729_forward_NZ_AP022607.1_Mycobacterium_branderi
> ORF_112064_LEN_57_COORD_2618559-2618729_forward_NZ_AP022607.1_Mycobacterium_branderi
> ORF_112062_LEN_65_COORD_2618535-2618729_forward_NZ_AP022607.1_Mycobacterium_branderi
> ORF_224113_LEN_59_COORD_900663-900487_reverse_NZ_AP022608.1_Mycolicibacterium_gadium
> ORF_224110_LEN_67_COORD_900687-900487_reverse_NZ_AP022608.1_Mycolicibacterium_gadium
> ORF_79139_LEN_59_COORD_1475341-1475517_forward_NZ_CP007220.1_Mycobacteroides_chelonae
> ORF_116852_LEN_77_COORD_3581529-3581299_reverse_NZ_AP022587.1_Mycobacterium_stomatepiae
> ORF_116851_LEN_79_COORD_3581535-3581299_reverse_NZ_AP022587.1_Mycobacterium_stomatepiae
> ORF_116850_LEN_81_COORD_3581541-3581299_reverse_NZ_AP022587.1_Mycobacterium_stomatepiae
> ORF_116849_LEN_84_COORD_3581550-3581299_reverse_NZ_AP022587.1_Mycobacterium_stomatepiae
> ORF_178001_LEN_86_COORD_4676508-4676251_reverse_NZ_CP078145.1_Nocardia_iowensis
> ORF_178000_LEN_89_COORD_4676517-4676251_reverse_NZ_CP078145.1_Nocardia_iowensis
> ORF_219647_LEN_84_COORD_621170-620919_reverse_NZ_AP022616.1_Mycolicibacterium_phocaicum
> ORF_219646_LEN_86_COORD_621176-620919_reverse_NZ_AP022616.1_Mycolicibacterium_phocaicum
> ORF_219645_LEN_89_COORD_621185-620919_reverse_NZ_AP022616.1_Mycolicibacterium_phocaicum
> ORF_219644_LEN_94_COORD_621200-620919_reverse_NZ_AP022616.1_Mycolicibacterium_phocaicum
> ORF_219649_LEN_54_COORD_621080-620919_reverse_NZ_AP022616.1_Mycolicibacterium_phocaicum
> ORF_40651_LEN_77_COORD_5220442-5220212_reverse_NZ_CP089224.1_Mycobacterium_ostraviense
> ORF_40650_LEN_79_COORD_5220448-5220212_reverse_NZ_CP089224.1_Mycobacterium_ostraviense
> ORF_40646_LEN_89_COORD_5220478-5220212_reverse_NZ_CP089224.1_Mycobacterium_ostraviense
> ORF_40648_LEN_84_COORD_5220463-5220212_reverse_NZ_CP089224.1_Mycobacterium_ostraviense
> ORF_40649_LEN_81_COORD_5220454-5220212_reverse_NZ_CP089224.1_Mycobacterium_ostraviense
> ORF_26333_LEN_47_COORD_546668-546808_forward_NZ_CP059165.1_Mycobacterium_vicinigordonae
```

So for instance, I need to choose the longest between those four ORFs from the NZ_AP022573.1_Mycobacterium_saskatchewanense strain with the 3965415 stop codon which would be ORF_150482 (with length 89)